# JQuery TableSorter not Recognizing Table on JSP Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, tablesorter

I'm playing around with trying to make tablesorter work for a simple table created using JSP and a Java Bean that reads information from the file.

Here is my jsp that creates the table:

```
    <% 

out.println("<table id=\"infoTable\" class=\"tablesorter\" border=\"1\" bgcolor=\"#57976b\" " +
    "style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\">");

//Print Table Headings
out.println("<thead><tr>");
for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    String par = parameters.get(i);
    out.println("<td>" + par + "</td>");        
}
out.println("</tr></thead>");

out.println("<tbody>");
ArrayList<String> values = fileBean.getAllValues();
for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {

    if(i%19 == 0) { 
        out.println("<tr>");
    }

    out.println("<td>" + values.get(i) + "</td>");

    if(values.get(i).contains("grading") && i%19 != 0) { 
        out.println("</tr>");   
    }

}
out.println("</tbody>");


out.println("</table>");

%>
```

With this script in my `<head>` tag:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#infoTable").tablesorter();
    })
</script>
```

And here is the HTML created using inspect element on the said page:

```
<table id="infoTable" class="tablesorter" border="1" bgcolor="#57976b"     style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead><tr>
<td>Grading</td>
<td>Teaching</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Title</td>
<td>Home Address</td>
<td>Additional Details</td>
<td>Course Name</td>
<td>Course Credits</td>
<td>Student ID</td>
<td>Additional Duties</td>
<td>Details</td>
<td>Course Grade</td>
<td>Phone Number</td>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1 </td>
<td>1 </td>
<td>John Doe</td>
<td>Student </td>
<td>Home Address </td>
<td>Web Development! </td>
<td>SWE 432 </td>
<td>4 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The values don't match the headers as this is just an example. I have included `<thead>` and `<tbody>` appropriately and the table looks just how I want it. Any idea why tablesorter is not recognizing my table?

Comment: At least in the HTML code you pasted, you are missing a closing <tr> tag in the body. Maybe jQuery's table sorted is not recognizing the table because it is not well-formed.

Comment: First make sure jquery is being initialized and working. Just put some javascript alert within document.ready to confirm. If its working then make sure table html is available when script fires. For this you can do another alert for table html like alert($("#infoTable").html()); Hopefully it will narrow down the issue.

Comment: I have confirmed Jquery and it is working when the table is recognized. Even after fixing the </tr> problem still no luck.

Comment: Did you try clicking on the header cell? Without a stylesheet, no sort arrows are added. Also, initialize tablesorter like this for testing: `.tablesorter({ debug: true })`, then look at the console log.

Comment: Also, [`bgcolor` has been deprecated](http://webdesign.about.com/od/intermediatetutorials/a/aa080502a.htm) in HTML 4.0 and XHTML.